# IBM ODM: multiple rulesets and wsdl files sharing the objects

Tags: web-services, xsd, wsdl, ibm-odm

I have an object model in the code and two different rulesets. Each ruleset is exposed as a separate endpoint with its own wsdl file. So, basically I have two endpoints and two wsdl files, however each wsdl contains definition of shared objects in the `wsdl:types/xsd:schema` section.

The problem is - the definitions in each embedded xsd reference the namespace of a rulesets, say:

```
<xs:complexType name="myObject">
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="element" type="ns:myElement"/>
  <xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

where ns is defined as

- "http://www.ibm.com/rules/decisionservice/MyApplication/Operation1"
  in first wsdl and
- "http://www.ibm.com/rules/decisionservice/MyApplication/Operation2"
  in the second wsdl.

That way for consumers generating the code from those wsdl files `myElement` objects can be treated like completely different.

Is there any way to generate external shared xsd schema and reference it from each wsdl instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not.

You can submit this as a Request for Enhancement here:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=changeRequestLanding&BRAND_ID=0&PROD_ID=536&x=22&y=16